# Exposing ports 502 and 1002 from NodeJS using Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

Trying to Expose port 502 and 1002 from NodeJS using Bluemix but I am not able to do that.
Does anyone have same issue on this?
Any suggestions or tips on this will be great.

Thank You

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're trying to do? Why are you trying to expose two ports? What protocols are you serving over the ports?

Answer (score 4):

[Cloud Foundry](http://cloudfoundry.org) is the technology platform used by [IBM Bluemix](http://bluemix.net). Applications running on this platform don't explicitly define external application ports.

Applications are expected to bind to a local port, given by a [environment variable](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html), for serving HTTP traffic. Cloud Foundry will forward all external requests received for your application's URL to this internal port.

Cloud Foundry will only forward HTTP, HTTPS and Websocket traffic. It is not possible to expose a non-HTTP protocol over the internal application port.